# How to restrict the Log File size growth

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i have installed sql server 2005 in windows server 2003.
Now MDF size is 11 MB but LDF size is 320 GB and it generated with in 8 months.

how to restrict the LDF growth and what are the reason for the growth.

regards,
Bharath

Comment: I am guessing that you are the DBA. Why don't you know this ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I am developer... Is it good way to restrict autogrowth of logfile?

Answer (score 0):

You don't restrict the Log file, that would be very very bad.  Perform backups of the database and the log file will take care of it's self.  The fact the log file is 320 gb, after the first backup you will want to shrink the log file, then it will take care of its own size.

Comment: thanks for the answer... I did it by converting the database recovery model simple from full recovery and then shrink  the database. Now log file size is less.

Comment: By switching to simple, you no longer have log files, so a point in time restore is no longer an option.  Not a great idea depending on what sort of activity the DB is seeing.